# I cant display my downloaded images on my app

Tags: java, android, arrays, random, bitmap

in the update status method:

```java
public void updateStatus() {

    Random random = new Random();
    URLSize = celebURLs.size();

    if (URLSize <= 0) {
        URLSize++;
        //chosenImage = random.nextInt(URLSize);
    } else {
        chosenImage = random.nextInt(URLSize);
    }

    ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
    Bitmap celebPics;

    try {
        celebPics = imageDownloader.execute(celebURLs.get(chosenImage)).get();
        imageView.setImageBitmap(celebPics);

        locationOfCorrectAnswer = random.nextInt(4);
        int incorrectAnswer;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (i == locationOfCorrectAnswer) {
                answers[i] = chosenNames.get(chosenImage);
            } else {
                incorrectAnswer = random.nextInt(celebURLs.size());
                while (incorrectAnswer == chosenImage) {
                    incorrectAnswer = random.nextInt(celebURLs.size());
                }
                answers[i] = chosenNames.get(incorrectAnswer);
            }

        }
        button1.setText(String.format("%s", answers[0]));
        button2.setText(String.format("%s", answers[1]));
        button3.setText(String.format("%s", answers[2]));
        button4.setText(String.format("%s", answers[3]));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I changed the code because it brought up an exception"IllegealArgumentException n must be positive" but even after changing the code to always increment the size of random generated values of the array list, it still wont work

Comment: It wont work? But where did you tell what should happen?

Comment: do you need to see my whole code?

Comment: You should start a post telling what the code should do.

Comment: let me add a link to my github, if you could help me i'd appreciate it

Comment: https://github.com/tribeless/GuessTheCelebrity/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/guessthecelebrity/MainActivity.java

Comment: `You should start a post telling what the code should do`.

Comment: The app is supposed to get images and celebrity names and display that content for the user to select the appropriate name for the image presented

Comment: You should start your post with that was what i suggested.

Answer (score 0):

So the asynctask instance outputs a string of data and then you have put it as a Bitmap and want it to set as a source of an Imageview? That wouldn't be right.

First put the data in a byte array (This will be the output of the asynctask class). Then turn it into Bitmap:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, image.getWidth(),
                image.getHeight(), false));
```

Comment: lemme try this and get back to you